React updating state in useEffect leads into incomplete data
I need a React Component to show some pictures in a custom layout made out by 'n' number of flex layouts. Each of this flex has an array of pictures wrapped in another flex, with flex-direction: column. The goal is to achieve a layout similar to the CSS columns, but with a little more control on it.
Here's my code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import useStorage from "../hooks/useStorage"
import { Column } from "./Column"

const splitInColumns = (nCols, photos) => {
  if (Array.isArray(photos)) {
    const cols = new Array(nCols).fill(null).map(() => [])
    let count = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
      cols[count].push(photos.pop())
      count == nCols - 1 ? (count = 0) : count++
    }

    return cols
  }
}

function Album() {
  const params = useParams()
  const [isLoading, folder] = useStorage({ type: "get-album", path: `assets/albums/${params.albumID}` })
  const [album, setAlbum] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(folder)) {
      setAlbum(splitInColumns(3, folder))
    }
  }, [folder, isLoading])

  {
    isLoading && <p>Caricamento</p>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div className="flex w-5/6 h-full">
          {album.map((col, index) => (
            <Column
              key={index}
              items={col}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Album


The problem: I get less pictures than I actually should.
I guess the problem is the way I update the album state inside of the useEffect() hook. But shouldn't the album state be updated everytime folder changes? Why I get less images?

Wouldn't it be easier to use grid?

What debugging have you done to lead to your conclusion that the problem is updating state inside a useEffect?  What specifically do you mean by "I get less pictures"?  When debugging, which specific value isn't what you expect is to be?  What were you expecting it to be and why?  What is the observed runtime value of folder?  What is the observed runtime result of the call to splitInColumns(3, folder)?

The problem simply is that I'm using the pop() method to get the last item of folder, inside my splitInColumns, so I get exactly half of the items, because the useEffect reruns every time I do this (I guess).

you should try changing the splitInColumns function a little bit for example :
const splitInCOlumns = (nCol,photos) => {
if (Array.isArray(photos)){
const col = new Array(nCol).fill(null).map(() => []);

photos.forEach((photo,index)=> {
col[index % nCol].push(photo);
});
return col;
}
}

